# How to install extended latin A and B on umbraco

Tags: installation, umbraco

I must install extended latin A and B on umbraco but don't know how.  Any advice?

Comment: Can you give more details on your issue, as I'm not clear what you mean or what you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 2):

http://forum.umbraco.org/